# trying to keep my div below top divs

Tags: html

I have two divs horizontally, and then trying the third div at the bottom ,
but the third one also coming at the right side instead of bottom .

```
<div style="width=100%">
<div id="slider">Left</div>
<div id="slider">Right</div>
</div>
<div id="text">Bottom</div>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junaidp/CaZY7/123/)

please guide

thanks

Comment: ids are meant to be unique. Don't use same id name more than once. To avoid confusion, use class names. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/CaZY7/124/

Comment: Did you try adding a CSS `clear: both;` to a div below the inline divs (left and right) and above the bottom div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float.

```
  .clear{
       clear:both
  }
```

Here is the updated fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/CaZY7/125/

Also, don't use common id for multiple elements. Also, whenever you use float, it has to be cleared else the following elements may get affected.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
#slider {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    height:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:green;
    float:left;

}
#slider img {
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
}

#text {

    width:950px;
    height:215px;
    color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/CaZY7/126/)